# Custom per domain CSS in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer

We have an old web app, which would be much more usable if it could be visually tweaked a bit. Being in a corporate environment - IE (always using the latest version) is all I can use. Also app in question being 3rd-party - there's no way to change it's own CSS files.

Is there a way to use per domain injected custom CSS in internet Explorer.

Let's say I want to change the background-color of domain http://oldapp.localintranet/ - is there any way to make this happen?

- Place to put a custom.css-file?
- With an add-on/extension?

Comment: im not sure i understand, are you asking can you use custom css if the site is viewied in internet explorer ? Or are you asking can you have a setting in IE that if its visits a site use some custome css that is local to that copy of IE

Comment: Tried Greasemonkey?

Comment: @Prasad: Stuck with IE - can't use anything else.

Comment: @Damiqib check this link - http://superuser.com/questions/266509/greasemonkey-for-ie8

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to the application files? If so you can place a custom.css file after the last .css file in the header. CSS cascades and the last CSS styles/classes are ones which take effect most times. `!important` may be needed to override any inline styled elements or possibly some ID's.

You can override CSS for IE browsers only using condotional comments more on that here http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

If you do not have access to the CSS files, you would need to use an add-on in the browser which would load your custom.css when you browsed http://oldapp.localintranet/ But then you'd have to account for some people using Firefox and Chrome.